# sample_qdata in highfrequency package R is not loading

Tags: r, datetime

The error while loading the data set from highfrequency package

```
require(highfrequency)
View(sample_qdata)
Warning in View :
  there is no package called ‘timeDate’
Error in View : "package:timeDate" %in% search() | require("timeDate", quietly = TRUE) is not TRUE
```

Comment: `install.packages("timeDate")` and try again.

Comment: Thanks dear. it works.